# Copower functor

Tags: category-theory, tensor-products

Computing copowers and "tensoring with sets" often means the same thing. If a 
locally small category $\mathcal{C}$ has coproducts and if $S$ is a set then for any object
$C\in\mathcal{C}$ the copower

$S\cdot C \simeq \coprod_{s\in S} C$.

However I don't know how this works on morphism. I.e. is this a co- or a contravariant- (bi)functor and how does it act on given maps, say 
$f_{set}:S \to T$ or $f_{\mathcal{C}}: C \to D$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is a covariant functor $Set\times\mathcal{C}\to \mathcal{C}$.  Given  $f:S\to T$ and $g:C\to D$, the induced map $(f\cdot g):S\cdot C\to T\cdot D$ is the unique map such that if $s\in S$ and $i_s:C\to S\cdot C$ is the corresponding inclusion, then $(f\cdot g)i_s=i_{f(s)}g$, where $i_{f(s)}:D\to T\cdot D$ is the inclusion corresponding to $f(s)\in D$.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the quick answer. The textbooks I have seem to leave this one out. But you mean: $Set\times\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}$ !